# least squares with seasonal component in matlab

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I was reading a paper which looked at investigating trends in monthly wind speed data for the past 20 years or so. The paper uses a number of different statistical approaches, which I am trying to replicate here.

The first method used is a simple linear regression model of the form

$$ y(t) = a_{1}t + b_{1} $$

where $a_{1}$ and $b_{1}$ can be determined by standard least squares.

Then they specify that some of the potential error in the linear regression model can be removed explicitly by accounting for the seasonal signal by fitting a model of the form:

$$ y(t) = a_{2}t + b_{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{12t} + c_{2}\right) + d_{2}$$

where coefficients $a_{2}$, $b_{2}$, $c_{2}$, and $d_{2}$ can be determined by least squares. They then go on to specify that this model was also tested with additional harmonic components of 3, 4, and 6 months.

Using the following data as an example:

```
 %   1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959 1960
y = [112  115  145  171  196  204  242  284  315  340  360  417    % Jan
     118  126  150  180  196  188  233  277  301  318  342  391    % Feb
     132  141  178  193  236  235  267  317  356  362  406  419    % Mar
     129  135  163  181  235  227  269  313  348  348  396  461    % Apr
     121  125  172  183  229  234  270  318  355  363  420  472    % May
     135  149  178  218  243  264  315  374  422  435  472  535    % Jun
     148  170  199  230  264  302  364  413  465  491  548  622    % Jul
     148  170  199  242  272  293  347  405  467  505  559  606    % Aug
     136  158  184  209  237  259  312  355  404  404  463  508    % Sep
     119  133  162  191  211  229  274  306  347  359  407  461    % Oct
     104  114  146  172  180  203  237  271  305  310  362  390    % Nov
     118  140  166  194  201  229  278  306  336  337  405  432 ]; % Dec

time = datestr(datenum(yr(:),mo(:),1));
jday = datenum(time,'dd-mmm-yyyy');
y2 = reshape(y,[],1);

plot(jday,y2)
```

Can anyone demonstrate how the model above can be written in matlab?

Comment: Have  a look on how to do least squares on matlab: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html

Comment: What you could do is calculating all the combinations of t, and fit them into a linear regression.

Comment: You could expand the sin() term into a power series and then do a regular least squares fit for a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your model is actually linear, we can use a [trigonometric identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to show that. To use a nonlinear model use [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html#btldemp-2).

Using your data I wrote the following script to compute and compare the different methods:

(you can comment out the `opts.RobustWgtFun = 'bisquare';` line to see that it's exactly like the linear fit with the 12 periodicity)

```
% y = [112  115 ...
y2 = reshape(y,[],1);
t=(1:144).';

% trend
T = [ones(size(t)) t];
B=T\y2;
y_trend = T*B;

% least squeare, using linear fit and the 12 periodicity only
T = [ones(size(t)) t sin(2*pi*t/12) cos(2*pi*t/12)];
B=T\y2;
y_sincos = T*B;

% least squeare, using linear fit and 3,4,6,12 periodicities
addharmonics = [3 4 6];
T = [T bsxfun(@(h,t)sin(2*pi*t/h),addharmonics,t) bsxfun(@(h,t)cos(2*pi*t/h),addharmonics,t)];
B=T\y2;
y_sincos2 = T*B;

% least squeare with bisquare weights, 
% using non-linear model of a linear fit and the 12 periodicity only
opts = statset('nlinfit');
opts.RobustWgtFun = 'bisquare';
b0 = [1;1;0;1];
modelfun = @(b,x) b(1)*x+b(2)*sin((b(3)+x)*2*pi/12)+b(4);
b = nlinfit(t,y2,modelfun,b0,opts);

% plot a comparison
figure
plot(t,y2,t,y_trend,t,modelfun(b,t),t,y_sincos,t,y_sincos2)
legend('Original','Trend','bisquare weight - 12 periodicity only', ...
    'least square - 12 periodicity only','least square - 3,4,6,12 periodicities', ...
    'Location','NorthWest');
xlim(minmax(t'));
```

[image: Comparison of the fitted curves]